# My brownie won't install. it's telling me "Microsoft Visual C++ v14.0 or more required" i have installed a new vs studio redist 2017 c++ package

Tags: visual-c++, installation, ethereum, chainlink, brownie

C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Blockchain\Burrockuchen projects\BrownieSimpleStorage> pipx install eth-brownie
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
C:\Users\ACER.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2022-08-06_15.50.29_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
bitarray
cytoolz
lru-dict

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
error: legacy-install-failure

Error installing eth-brownie.

C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Blockchain\Burrockuchen projects\BrownieSimpleStorage>

Comment: You don't need a redist, you need a compiler.

Comment: And how do you suggest i get this compiler my good man

Comment: Following the link in your question or the instructions in the answer would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

"Download and install the [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/), and then install the `C++ build tools`. Once installed, run the following command in your terminal. [Here is a video tutorial showing you how to install the build tools.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcI1_e38BWs)"

Then do:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install eth-brownie
```

Reference = https://chain.link/bootcamp/brownie-setup-instructions